# python random_sample minimum value

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, random

I am currently using random_sample to generate weightage allocation for 3 stocks where each row values add up to 1.

```
for portfolio in range (10):
    weights = np.random.random_sample(3)
    weights  = weights/ np.sum(weights)
    print (weights)

[0.39055438 0.44055996 0.16888567]
[0.22401792 0.26961926 0.50636282]
[0.67856154 0.21523207 0.10620639]
[0.33449127 0.36491387 0.30059486]
[0.55274192 0.23291811 0.21433997]
[0.20980909 0.38639029 0.40380063]
[0.24600751 0.199761   0.5542315 ]
[0.50743661 0.26633377 0.22622962]
[0.1154567  0.36803903 0.51650427]
[0.29092731 0.34675988 0.36231281]
```

I am able to do it but is there any way to ensure that the minimum weightage allocation is greater than 0.05? Meaning that the minimum weight allocation could only be something like [0.05 0.9 0.05]

Comment: Running your code gives: TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len(), should be ```np.random.random_sample(3)```

Comment: Yup, sorry my bad, copied the wrong code. But I am still unsure on how to input a minimum weightage of 0.05 for each stock

Comment: What if you just kept generating, deleting those that have less than 0.05

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can ignore them:

```
n = 0
while n < 10:
    weights = np.random.random_sample(3)
    weights  = weights/ np.sum(weights)
    if any(i < 0.05 for i in weights):
        continue
    n += 1
    print (weights)
```

Comment: But in this case, I would not be able to generate exactly 10 sets of weightage allocation since I am dropping those sets that have I <0.05. Would end up having 7-8 sets

Comment: @Cedric An easy fix incoming

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.random_sample.html#numpy.random.random_sample)

> Results are from the “continuous uniform” distribution over the stated interval. To sample *Unif(a,b), b>a* multiply the output of `random_sample` by `(b-a)` and add `a`.

In this case, `0.95 * weight + 0.05`